# Кодировка в java

Tags: кодировка, java

Есть строка символов типа "&# 036;", как их преобразовать в нормальные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писать свой класс и дергать соответствие символов вручную или взять готовое решение. 
e.g. Apache Commons Lang - > [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Вообще то любой более-менее нормальный XML редактор иксемельные ентити автоматом преобразовывает в читаемые на экране символы, так что можно спокойно копипастить в текст или из текста.

**Примеры:** [ExchangerXML](http://www.exchangerxml.com/), Visual Studio, Intellij IDEA (по моему), [XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/download/xmlspy/xml_editor_enterprise.html) (правда он небесплатен) и проч.